# Application with session management in the server side

Tags: php, ios, session

I need to create a server based (php) application with iOS client with authintication "login" mechanisim but i dont known about session in iOS. My application needs login to my website (PHP based website) to get data. I dont known a is the session for the iPhone client is keept in the server?

Details:

After sending the login request from iPhone client to my web application, I think here a session is created in my webapp (right?), what about my next request? can I access the same session created for the first request.. In another word : can I share data in the web session (in the server) to be accessible in each request sent by iOS client after login?

Comment: PHP server based iOS app, doesnt make sense...

Comment: Yes, it does - don't be pedantic. He obviously means an iOS app that acts as a client that talks to a back-end server written in PHP.

Comment: Dear Yahia, Thank you for your advice, could you please clarify you comment

Comment: Dear Cariag1231, I meant exactly what "Nick Lockwood" mentioned

Comment: I got it, many thanks to all of you :)

Comment: Dears, I updated the question's body to be more clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sessions are a server-side concept - there is no session on the client side.

What normally happens is that the server sets a cookie in the response headers after you log in, and that cookie contains the session ID so that on subsequent requests, the server knows that the client is using that session because it matches up the cookie.

Cookies work automatically on iOS, so you shouldn't have to do anything at all. NSURLRequests have a property HTTPShouldHandleCookies that defaults to YES, so everything should just work by default.

If it's not working (or if you just want to see what's going on), you can gain access to the cookies in iOS using the NSHTTPCookieStorage APIs. Take a look inside the [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage], which works a bit like an NSDictionary. That's where the session cookie should be set after you log in.

Comment: +1 for entirely correct answer. Just one addition, the session does not *have* to be kept using cookies - it could be a get-parameter as well, depending on the server/PHP setup.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I decided to omit that from the answer to avoid complicating things, but it's a valid point.

Comment: +1 this is fantastic, this is exactly what I needed to read too, cheers!