# authentication in iOS - can you use cookies/session?

Tags: php, iphone, authentication

I'd like to serve info from PHP to an iPhone app based on what user's logged in. Can I go the session/cookie route of authenticating requests from the app or do I have to use some sort of token authentication? Basically, can php leave cookies (same as on a browser) if i'm calling the services from iPhone app?

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic. In your iOS app, just make sure to accept and store cookies correctly for the authentication to be persistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the NSHTTP methods handle cookies behind the scenes.

And you can configure behavior as well with [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the "behind the scenes" link is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

This is the [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLRequest) documentation. I think the link to the NSHTTPCookie is more under the hood than is needed for this question.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148844/1312094)