# CakePHP Sessions and Safari on iOS 6.1.3

Tags: ios, session, cakephp, safari

I have a CakePHP application (using cake 2.3) which uses the Session component to show the user a splash page the first time he/she comes to the site, and never again. Here's the code in the controller:

```
public function index() {
  if (!$this->Session->check('splashShown')) {
    $this->Session->write('splashShown', true);
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action' => 'about'));
  }
  //other stuff in controller...
}
```

This works perfectly on desktop versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome. It also works fine on Chrome iOS, but not in Safari iOS. In Safari, the Session->check() function always returns false.

Anyone know whats going on with sessions on Safari iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569135/authentication-in-ios-can-you-use-cookies-session) it handles the same problem, iOS is a bit different in this.

Also look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-BAJEAIEE) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). @Sam Delaney is right of the problem.

Comment: not sure why you pointed to objective C libraries - I'm talking about an HTML app with a CakePHP backend.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it's to do with the session cookie being stored on the internet browser since I believe this the default mechanism PHP uses to persist the session across requests. Upon request, if PHP fails to identify the session ID, it creates a new one and in the response to the client, sets a cookie with the ID of the session.

#### Edit

To verify this is the case, I quickly googled for you and I came across this: http://rf.com/how-to/how-to-enable-cookies-on-the-iphone/ Obviously this does not fix the problem but will help you identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: This will not solve the problem with users, since you cannot always expect every user to have them enabled. @Abhishek Agrawal if this is the only way for this, think of a way to notify your users about this.
I think there was a solution somewhere. I will check and come back to you all.

Comment: This assumes that not storing the cookie is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, it does. And it could (maybe is) the problem, however you cannot expect every user to have this enabled nor can you expect them to want to enable it. So the app will need to notify the users of this need.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help, unfortunately, the test suggested by @SamDelaney failed, i.e. even after the Accept Cookies setting was set to "Always" for Safari, the function returns false.