# 400 with file_gets_contents() or curl_init()

Tags: file-get-contents, php-curl, http-status-code-400

Most of the site sources, opens with a simple request, usualy by `file_gets_contents()` or `curl_init()`.

I've tried a lot of combinations of `stream_context_create()` and `curl_setopt()`, and **none** returned any thing different of 400 bad request.

Is there an explanation for why some server-sites ( like https://phys.org/ ) do not return de source code by quoted methods?

obs.: if you were able to get the source of the exemple ( https://phys.org/ ), using `file_gets_contents() or curl_init()`, or any other method with php, please post the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some Website's are validating the request if it comes from a real/allowed client (bot/user).
This can have multiple reasons.

Maybe the bots are sending to many requests, or the specific site is blocked behind a paywall/firewall. But there are many other people who can explain it to you better then me.

Here are some known Examples how they did it:

Some Site's are supporting request with an [API-Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784908/what-is-an-api-token).
[Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)'s are an great example.

Some Site's are validing the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).
It looks like that your example site is doing this.
When I'm sending a custom User-Agent Header the result is returning to an error.

And Of Course can some site's check for the User IP Address :)

I believe in your example there should be a good solution to get a result.

Comment: The site exemple,has also an feed under the link https://phys.org/rss-feed/, so it's somehow interesting that other sources get it's content. 

The feed link also return 400 bad request...

It's not about avoid bots or harvesting content.