# IOS-how to implement sssions for autologin in app through php

Tags: php, ios, mysql, session, authentication

hello i am new in ios and working on a project in which i need autologin
i store my login details in remote database(MySql) 
now i want user will be logged to the application until he/she clicked on logout button for this i create session in php file but it is not working
someone please help me to overcome from this problem

My php codes are given below

```
<?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $db = 'proj';
    //$dbtable = 'login';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    //$sql="SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE $_SESSION[email]='$email' and $_SESSION[password]='$password'";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1)
    {
        echo "Success";
        //session_start();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }    
?>
```

.M file

```
 - (IBAction)login:(id)sender
            {
                            NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/select.php?email=%@&password=%@",userid.text,password.text ];
                        NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
                        NSString *st=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        NSLog(@"%@",st);
                        if([st isEqualToString:@"Success"])
                        {
                            NSLog(@"fff");
                            mainpage *q=  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainpage"];
                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:q animated:YES];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"invalid username or password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                            [alert show];
                        }

            }
```

Comment: Sessions create cookies, you need to send them along in every request or use a session token, etc. More important: DONT EVER SEND / STORE / COMPARE passwords in clear text, ALWAYS hash and salt them.

Answer (score 0):

First what is your sesssion timeout set for php service your have written, for example if this is 30 seconds then you need to keep requesting calls or maintain cookie value from iOS app (refer :- [Application with session management in the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148594/application-with-session-management-in-the-server-side) ). Also you php code doesnt show any session created, I hope your creating a sesssion as explained in the this link :- http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/